# Parsing wiki markup using a state machine

Tags: java, clojure, state-machine

I would like to parse a simple grammar such as wiki markup using state machines. I have never written or played with one. I would like to lean how to implement a simple one. I am thinking of using Clojure for this. My question is can you point me to some good tutorials that are for complete newbies on this topic such as my self?

Comment: If you've ever used a ballpoint pen with a retract button, you've played with a state machine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [fnparse](http://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse). It is a Clojure library for functional parsing and contains a really good example of JSON parsing. [Parser](http://kotka.de/projects/clojure/parser.html) is another library that might be helpful also. Even if you don't wish to use them, they provide some great insights into parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Try Miro Samek's Book on State Machines. [Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++](http://www.state-machine.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [state machine compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/), to avoid a lot of boring code.
It will produce Jars and Clojure - Java interop is good.

Comment: But he wants to _implement_ one, right, not just have a useable one?